# Possible explanation for why "SELECT" query executed from JDBC returning just the first row in the table

Tags: oracle, query, select, java, oracle-21c

I installed OracleDB(XE - free version) and I tried to use it in Java. I have this code:

```
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE";
       static final String USER = "AdministratorPDB1";
       static final String PASS = "admin.admin";
       static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
          ) {             
             while(rs.next()){
                //Display values
                System.out.print(rs.getString("fam_name"));
                System.out.print("          ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("giv_name"));
                System.out.print("          ");
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("age"));
                System.out.print("          ");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("email") + "\n");
             }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } 
       }
```

For some reason, the program seems to print just the first row from the table. I can confirm the fact that there are more entries in that table if I open Windows Command Prompt, connect using `sqlplus` command, and run the `SELECT * FROM TestTable;`, query, all three rows are printed in the command line.

I also tried to loop over the rows like this:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
        String colName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
        String colValue = resultSet.getString(i);
        System.out.println(colName + ": " + colValue);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The same problem. Just the first entry is displayed.
It seems to have something to do with `resultSet.next()`.

Now, I know I might have not given enough information for a solve, but this is all I got. This is a hard problem to debug.

OracleDB version: **21c** 
Java version: **jdk 1.8.0**

Comment: "This is a hard problem to debug" -- I don't think it is, but have you done _any_ debugging? Like, actually using a debugger?

Comment: WDYM? What debugging I can do. I just call a method from a library, how should I get low-level access to what's happeing behind the scenes with the `.next()` method?

Comment: Fire up your favourite debugger, step into `next()`, and enjoy the magic show. However, I suspect that, whatever is happening, is happening _outside_ `next()`.